# Hudson style build reports on developer machines/within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hudson

We use Hudson for our continuous integration which provides us with easy to browse build reports showing compiler warnings, unit test results and coverage (EMMA), pmd, checkstyle and findbugs violations.

Although we each have the relevant plugins installed locally in Eclipse, it often seems easier to simply commit to SVN in order to trigger a Hudson build and generate a build report showing the above info rather than checking with each plugin.

Is there something that developers could install locally (i.e. an Eclipse plugin perhaps) to generate similar reports? Or would it be feasible to somehow use Hudson for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also install Sonar, which includes all the tools you list (except EMMA which is a plugin). Try it, it's free and open source ! http://sonar.codehaus.org

Answer (score 1):

You Can install hudson locally easily. It is a runnable jar.

Try it. You'll like it.